# What non-flash abilities can get you out of Jarvan IV's ultimate?

Tags: league-of-legends

I want to counter Jarvan IV when he plays against me in the top lane.  His Ultimate is my biggest problem, since when he uses it, the jungler can run past my ward and gank me.  Flash has a longer cooldown than his ult, which is a problem. What characters have the ability to get out of his ult without using Flash?  I'm most interested in top lane characters, but a list of any will do.

Comment: Kayle is an effective counter to Jarvan in terms of ultimates. You simply ult after he ults negating his damage. This question is a bit localized in my opinion but not localized enough for a close vote.

Comment: That's helpful Edem, but I really want to know who can get out of the ult.  I need to escape, not endure.

Comment: Tristana's rocket jump gets you out, but she isn't really top lane normally.

Comment: Okey. I'm not experienced enough to answer your question but I had some fun with Kayle playing against Jarvan. That's why I just commented.

Comment: I know Renekton's dash also gets me out.  I'm hoping someone has a compiled list of all abilities/characters though.

Comment: I think most cap-closers can get out of the ultimate (like irelias q) but it might even worsen your position. (depending on enemy jungler)

Comment: You probably should be warding top so you know when the jungle is coming.  That means you wont need a character who can get out of his ult at all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just wanted to make a list on my own, but then I found this:

[Jarvan's Ultimate = Impassable Terrain](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=522518)

Guess this should answer the question. But credits to the thread opener from the LoL Board!

As requested in the comments here the list copied from the link above. Still all credits for this list belong to the Thread opener King Gary IV out of the LoL Forum EU West.

- Ahri's Spirit Fire
- Akali's Shadow Dash
- Alistar's Headbutt
- Amumu's Bandage Toss
- Caitlyn's 90 Caliber Net
- Corki's Valkyrie
- Ezreal's Arcane shift
- Fiora's Lunge or Blade Waltz
- Fizz's Playful/Trickster
- Gragas's Body Slam
- Graves's Quickdraw
- Hecarim's Devastating Charge
- Irelia's Bladesurge
- Jax's Leap Strike
- Kennen's Lightning Rush
- Kassadin's Riftwalk
- Katarina's Shunpoo
- Kha'zix's Leap
- LeBlanc's Distortion
- LeeSin's Safeguard/Sonic Wave
- Leona's Zenith Blade
- Lulu's Wild Growth
- Malphite's Unstoppable Force
- Maokai's Twisted Advance
- Master Yi's Alpha Strike
- Nautilus's Dredge Line
- Nidalee's Pounce
- Nocturne's Paranoia
- Pantheon's Aegis of Ziona
- Poppy's Heroic Charge
- Renekton's Slice & Dice
- Riven's Broken Wings
- Sejuani's Artic Assault
- Shaco's Deceive
- Shen's Shadow Dash
- Shyvana's Dragon's Descent
- Talon's Cutthroat
- Tristana's RocketJump
- Tryndamere's Spinning Slash
- Twisted Fate's Destiny
- Urgot's Hyper-Kinetic Position Reverser
- Vayne's Tumble
- Warwick's Infinity Duress
- Wukong's Nimbus Strike
- Xin Zhao's Audacious Charge
- Zigg's Satchel Charge

> Also if Jarvan ulties and you ghost, you'll keep on running through it like nothing happened because Catacalysm is basically coded like 'a wall of minions' just like with Anivia's Wall.

Comment: This is perfect.  Thanks Toby!  Upvote coming whenever I hit 15 rep...

Comment: @Toby For the sake of completion, can you copy the list of abilities to your answer here? While it's definitely appropriate to link your source, as you have done, copying the relevant information here will prevent your answer from being deprecated due to link rot.

Comment: I agree with FAE. Could you quote some of the relevant information into your answer. It'll also make the answer more valuable to future readers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if Sejuani uses her Artic Assault, it busts open a hole for other to simply walk out off. This may be related to the "being able to run through it with Ghost" bug.

Comment: im certain that if there is another enemy champ nearby that Darius can ult jump out of there.

Comment: wukongs clone can at least i did it with his clone

Comment: I *think* Kha'zix's Leap can escape it too

Comment: I once ran trough it with udyr's bear stance. But I couldn't recreate it ;)
And as Landric said, kha'zix's leaps can jump out aswell.

Comment: If being able to go through units is enough, isn't phantom lancer a solution then? And fizz's passive should do as well.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that has can displace you over the wall can get you out of Jarvan's Cataclysm.

Some examples are:

- Corki's w: Valkyrie
- Ezreal's E: Arcane Shift
- Caitlyn's E: 90 Caliber Net
- Gragas's E: Body Slam
- Maplhite's R: Unstoppable Force
- Jax's Q: Leap Strike (if used on an enemy on the outside of the wall)

*These are not all of the possible skills/champions who can escape Jarvan's Cataclysm, there are certainly more.*

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade @Brandon Stein! In case you are wondering about the downvotes on your answer they are becasue your answer is a bit unfinished and unorganized. Answers on here should always be complete, concise and clearly stated. I have edited your answer so you can see what I mean.

Answer (score -4):

Anything that displaces ur champion in any way works too
Wukong W
Shaco R